# How to expand all inline block divs to fill parent?

Tags: html, css

If I have something like this

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.B, .C {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

For both B and C, the width wraps it's content and doesn't fill width of A fully. But if I set its width to 100%, then each width is equal to the width of A, which then extends A to twice it's original size in width.

How can I change it so that, the width of B + the width of C = the original width of A.

Basically increase the width of B and C such that it fills the width of A, but keep them inline.

Does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: 100% divided by 2 = 50% - tried that?

Comment: Also, this is dynamic, 2 children is just an example, it could have any number of children. Also I don't want to fix it's width, it should adjust based on it content size too. Because if I use 50%, then what if it's content required 70%.

Comment: I don't like tables because I also want them to wrap if the screen width gets too small.

Comment: @omega Check my answer using FlexBox.

Comment: This depends on how you expect the wrapping inside B & C to work. There are couple of solution (flexbox & CSS tables) that would work but they will depend on the required behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The best use-case for this would be using `Flexbox` as you are saying they are dynamic:

```css
.A {border: 1px solid #99f;}
.A div {border: 1px solid #999; height: 10px;}

/* Flex Box */
.A {display: flex;}
.A div {flex: auto;}
```

```html
Two:
<div class="A">
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
</div>

Three:
<div class="A">
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
</div>

Random:
<div class="A">
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
  <div class="B"></div>
  <div class="C"></div>
  <div class="D"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the inner divs had content, then do the divs wrap if the screen width get too small? I don't want them all to remain in 1 line causing overflow.

Comment: @omega You can set them using `@media` queries... `:)`

Comment: I tried it in jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/smp1krk8/ and if the width becomes too small, then they don't wrap and just overflow.

Comment: @omega You didn't use `@media` queries. That's why.

Comment: I am not sure that will work as I don't know what fixed width to use for changing the style in the media query since it's dynamic content.

Comment: @omega I understand. This is just my idea.

Comment: Maybe, @Paulie_D can improve this answer or provide a better solution. `:)`

Comment: @omega The `FlexBox` model is somewhat similar to the tables.

Comment: I agree flexbox is likely to be the optimal solution but we don't know enough about the intended behaviour of the content to completely recommended it (IMO).

Comment: @Paulie_D Completely agree with you. What's the problem in having the content coming in multi-line?

Comment: Flexbox and tables almost behave the same, they don't wrap when screen width becomes too small. That's why I started out with inline blocks.

Comment: @omega I tried giving `min-width`, but trying it yet. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is not as elegant as Praveen Kumar's answer, but I thought I'd post a table-based answer:

```css
.A {
    display: table;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 2px solid #000;
}
.A > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
Example 1:

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
</div>

Example 2: 

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
</div>

Example 3: 

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
</div>

Example 4:

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
</div>

Example 5:

<div class="A">
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
    <div class="B"></div>
    <div class="C"></div>
    <div class="D"></div>
    <div class="E"></div>
    <div class="F"></div>
    <div class="G"></div>
</div>
```

Again, the amount of children is irrelevant. You can have as many as you require.

Comment: This gives the same output as mine, but we have another big issue to focus. Check the comments on my answer...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Ah, I'll take a look and see if I can revise my answer.

Comment: Not much you can do. But yea, have a look at the comments. That looks like a serious problem.

Comment: @PraveenKumar True, I think the OP may have to compromise to achieve an acceptable result here - there's a lot of unknowns / dynamic output to deal with...